# Obtaining data with mysql or R of a MSOLAP provider

Tags: mysql, r, olap-cube

I have an OLAP cube in excel with a MSOLAP but queries are too slow, so I would like to connect me from mysql or R. I have the following connection properties:

Provider=MSOLAP.4;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=anuser;Initial Catalog=SGD_CUBOS;Data Source=anurl;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error.

Is possible accessed from mysql or R?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have been trying to do the exact same thing as you for a bit. I don't have an answer, but can tell you what DOES NOT work.

I have tried using X4R.

```
#library(devtools)
#install_github("overcoil/X4R")
library(X4R)
handle<-xmlaConnect(url="cubos.sispro.gov.co",uid="sispro.local\\XXXXX", pwd="XXXXX")
```

This usually ends in a failed connection.

I have tried using RDCOMClient

```
#create connection to SSAS datacube
con <- COMCreate("ADODB.Connection")
con[["ConnectionString"]] <- paste(
    "Provider=MSOLAP.4",
    "Password=XXXX",
    "Persist Security Info=True",
    "User ID=sispro.local\\XXXX",
    "Data Source=cubos.sispro.gov.co",
    "Initial Catalog=CU_BDUA",
  sep = ";")
con$Open()
```

Hope this is useful

Comment: Telling the OP what does not work is not useful because the OP wants to know what is useful and what will happen them. To ask why your attempt isn't working please ask a new question